# Android custom views not being draw and canvas maximum size

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-canvas, hardware-acceleration

I'm developing an application that has an embedded chat on it.
In order to draw the bubbles* where the text is displayed, I'm using a custom view which extends from FrameLayout, just like in here:

https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView/blob/master/shapeofview/src/main/java/com/github/florent37/shapeofview/ShapeOfView.java

or here:

https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/BubbleLayout/blob/master/bl/src/main/java/com/daasuu/bl/BubbleLayout.java

*bubbles -> you know: the rounded corner rectangle with a little arrow at the left or right, depending on who wrote the message

The thing is that, if the message to be shown is long enough (a couple of thousands of characters depending on the phone's memory) the background drawable is not shown anymore.

I found that this is expected because I'm exceeding the maximum canvas size (the maximum height, in this case)

I know that the canvas maximum size in android depends on the phone on which you are measuring it.
For example, this is the limit for an old phone (Moto G 1st gen):

[image]

And this is the limit for a newer phone, with more memory:

[image]

Question: Is there another way you can think of, to define a view with an arbitrary shape as the background which overcomes this limitation?

PD: Yes, the code looks strange because I'm using xamarin to develop, but the question is general enough, and I don't care the language of the solution if it does exist :)

**UPDATE**
Added example code to reproduce this issue.

You just have to create any background in xml, let's say that we call it "bubble_background.xml":

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
```

And then use it as background for a TextView, like in :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bubble"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cell_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/atlas_text_size_message_item"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_background" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, if your text is long enough, the background won't be visible (it is a good idea to wrap the TextView in a ScrollView...)

**UPDATE**
This is the result of testing the background that was suggested by @cherryBu
Of course, I've got the same result because it is exactly what I was doing, but still, I had to test it, just in case, you know how this is.... :)

[image]

The top and bottom thin rectangles with round corners and the little triangle at the right (all in blue) are part of my current solution (one which doesn't make me happy but works: I'm "drawing" the bubble by composing it using those 3 partial images and setting the background of the text to the same color). The text is white, that's why you can't really see much of it. In the current code I'm setting the background to blue (not an image, because it can't be drawn -again :) -, only a plain color; the same as you can see in the other parts of the "bubble")

Comment: @Guilermo,According to your description, I guess that there is background drawable  in bubbles, it displays text, if the text is very long characters , the background don't show, is it? If yes, can you give sample that can reproduce your issue here?

Comment: Exactly, @CherryBu, it is like you think. It is really easy to reproduce, I've added some example code to the question, anyway

Comment: ,I use your code at my side, but I don't know any background for textView, I guess that you want to create shape for textView, the shape will disappear when text is long, but I do one simple sample, I don't have this issue, please see the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the one who originally posted the question and the same which suggests the hacky and ugly solution from below.

I found a better and proper solution to this issue: the canvas size limit is only a problem when you have the Hardware acceleration turned on; so once I turned it off, I was able to render bubbles of any size.

The hardware acceleration can be customized in different ways and at different levels: Application, Activity, Window, or even at the View level, with some limitations.

For more information about what can and can't be done, please refer to the Goggle's documentation about this topic: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel

Answer (score 0):

bubble_background.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For all properties see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
  <padding
    android:bottom="50dp"
    android:left="50dp"
    android:right="50dp"
    android:top="50dp" />
  <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#B2F7FE"/>
  <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

I use this as TextView background, I add very long text in it, but the shape still exist.

Update:

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I've done in the past to show the bubble background, but (as I said) it doesn't work with very very VERY long texts. In fact, and also as I said, the thing is not caused by the text lenght; it is a problem of the maximum canvas size where the background will be drawn, you should increase the text lenght if you are still able to see the background (as a reference, I needed to scroll down like 5 times in order to read all the text)

Comment: ....and just in case, I've tested your background, but of course, with a loooooooong text which implies a big canvas, it won't be visible. Seriously, test your example with much more text (or increase your font size, it doesn't matter) and you will see the background dissapearing

Comment: I forgot to thell you: You can see a new image attached to the original question, showing the test with your background

Comment: @Guillermo,yes, I add very very long text in TextView, I need to use scroll down like many times in order to read all the text, it still display shape. You can see the screenshot.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and effort, but it is clear to me from your last image that you are using a scroll for the text inside the "bubble", so your image height is only the size of the screen. Of course you can draw that, no problem there. As I said several times: is not a problem of the text itself, it is a problem of the image size exceeding the canvas size. Imagine a chat application: you don't scroll the text inside the bubble, you scroll the entire bubble with the text inside

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is struggling with this issue: there is no solution and the maximum canvas size cannot be changed nor exceeded if you want to display a background like in this case.

Workaround solution, for my particular case:
Each bubble is composed using 4 items and a relative layout:

1. an image at the top, a thin blue/green rectangle with round top corners
2. an image at the bottom, a thin blue/green rectangle with round bottom corners
3. the text itself, with the same blue/green color set as background
4. a little blue/green triangle located at the right or left, according to who is sending the message to complete the chat bubble

I did not find any other solution and this one is working.
Of course, this won't work for you if you want to use an image instead of a plain color or simple pattern as backgournd